# How to install MongoDB Connector for Spark in Azure Synapse Notebook?

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, azure-synapse

I want to install MongoDB Spark Connector in Azure Synapse, so I can write code like this in my Notebooks:

```
df = spark.read.format("mongodb").option("spark.synapse.linkedService", "MongoDB_MyCollection").load()
```

At the moment this fails saying "Failed to find data source: mongodb"

[Getting started guide for MongoDB Spark Connector](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/spark-connector/current/getting-started/)  says I should use `--packages org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector:10.0.2` flag when invoking`./bin/pyspark`, but I'm running PySpark code in Azure Synapse Notebooks, so I don't invoke `./bin/pyspark` myself.

Question - how can I install MongoDB Connector for Spark when running in Azure Synapse?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? im trying to do the same

Answer (score 0):

**Version 10.x** of the MongoDB Connector for Spark is an all-new connector based on the latest Spark API. Version 10.x uses the new namespace:

`com.mongodb.spark.sql.connector.MongoTableProvider`

There are various configuration options available. The following options for writing to MongoDB are available:

**Note:** If you use `SparkConf` to set the connector's write configurations, prefix `spark.mongodb.write.` to each property.

| Property Name | Description |
| --- | --- |
| `mongoClientFactory` | MongoClientFactory configuration key. You can specify a custom implementation which must implement the `com.mongodb.spark.sql.connector.connection.MongoClientFactory` interface. **Default:** `com.mongodb.spark.sql.connector.connection.DefaultMongoClientFactory` |
| `connection.uri` | **Required**. The connection string configuration key. Default: `mongodb://localhost:27017/` |
| `database` | **Required**. The database name configuration. |
| `collection` | **Required**. The collection name configuration. |
| `maxBatchSize` | Specifies the maximum number of operations to batch in bulk operations. Default: `512` |
| `ordered` | Specifies whether to perform ordered bulk operations. Default: `true` |
| `operationType` | Specifies the type of write operation to perform. You can set this to one of the following values: `insert`: insert the data. `replace`: replace an existing document that matches the `idFieldList` value with the new data, or insert the data if no match exists. `update`: update an existing document that matches the `idFieldList` value with the new data, or inserts the data if no match exists. Default: `replace` |
| `idFieldList` | Field or list of comma-separated fields to use to identify a document. Default: `_id` |
| `writeConcern.w` | Specifies `w`, a write concern option to acknowledge the level to which the change propagated in the MongoDB replica set. You can specify one of the following values: `MAJORITY`; `W1`, `W2`, or `W3`; `ACKNOWLEDGED`; `UNACKNOWLEDGED`. Default: `ACKNOWLEDGED` |
| `writeConcern.journal` | Specifies `j`, a write concern option to enable request for acknowledgment that the data is confirmed on on-disk journal for the criteria specified in the `w` option. You can specify either `true` or `false`. |
| `writeConcern.wTimeoutMS` | Specifies `wTimeoutMS`, a write concern option to return an error when a write operation exceeds the number of milliseconds. If you use this optional setting, you must specify a non-negative integer. |

You can refer the PySpark code that will read the CSV file into a stream, compute a moving average, and stream the results into MongoDB [here](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/new-mongodb-spark-connector).

Useful links: [Configuration options](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/spark-connector/current/configuration/), [Write Configuration Options](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/spark-connector/current/configuration/write/#connection.uri-configuration-setting)

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question. The question is focused on installing the connector in Synapse notebook (spark pool), where I don't have access to `--packages` flag.